# Scrollbar disabled in scenebuilder

Tags: javafx, scroll, scenebuilder

I have a problem with scrollbar (in ScrollPane control) in my fxml file in JavaFX SceneBuilder. I can see it but when I want to click on it and scroll nothing happends. I can`t access to controls in red ellipse and other below them. What is wrong with it and how can I solve it? Below I paste link to screen. 
[my fmxl file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODoTD.jpg)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it; SceneBuilder simply doesn't allow you to modify it's properties by interacting with the scrollbar. Adjust the `vvalue` property in the properties view of the scrollpane if you want to modify the initial vertical scrollbar position of your scene.

Comment: Thanks for helps, works.

Comment: Press `Ctrl+P` to see if it works.